# How do I get the exit status from the first command in a pipe within make?

Tags: windows, pipe, gnu-make, exit-code, tee

I'm trying to pipe to the output of the compiler to the tee command in windows, but I've ran into an issue where if the compiler fails within make it'll continue compiling the next file when I want to it to stop. Is there a way to have the exit status of the first command be the exit status of the second command?

```
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) 2>&1 | tee build_log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would leave any logging to the caller of make. Second off, this sort of piping is untidy in make. Third off, not a fan of losing the stderr stream *inside* make.

That said, this is a shell question. If you are using bash then see *pipefail* in the manual. Unfortunately I think it's quite tricky to turn on. (Yeah, I know you said windows, but I assume you aren't using the execrable *cmd*.)

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

passes:
    (exit 1) |& cat

fails:
    bash -c 'set -o pipefail; (exit 1) |& cat'
```

Comment: If you set SHELL to /bin/bash you don't need to use `bash -c ...` in the command line.  One or the other will do.  At least in a UNIX system... hopefully in Windows as well.  Although in Windows (unless you're using cygwin) that path won't work.

Comment: @MadScientist Is there a way to use the `SHELL` variable in a Makefile such that _bash_ will have the `pipefail` option enabled?

Comment: Not easily: bash doesn't support that as a command line option.  But all I meant above was you can just write `set -o pipefail; (exit 1) |& cat` you don't need to add the `bash -c` part.  The only way I know of to do it for all recipes without explicitly adding it to each one (either directory or via a variable) would be to create a file containing that command, say `initfile`, then add `export BASH_ENV = initfile` to your makefile.

Comment: `/bin/bash` on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

After Struggling a lot, I came to this solution ...

```
.ONESHELL:
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) 2> temp_err_file
    set EXIT_STATUS=%ERRORLEVEL%
    type temp_err_file >> build_log.txt
    type temp_err_file 1>&2
    del /q temp_err_file
    exit /b %EXIT_STATUS%
```

Here `.ONESHELL` allows make to run entire recipe in the single shell command instead of running each line in separate cmd and collect return status of each separately. Overall exit status depends on the main compilation command so in end it is necessary to exit with the status of compilation.

I know its not a clean solution involving the `temp_err_file` and if something goes wrong after compilation command, make would not be able to catch it but this I think is the best I can find to work with windows without losing stderr stream and logging.

Answer (score 0):

A method that is shell independent and may be feasible in some cases is the following:

assume you have a recipe:

```
target:
        try_making_target |& tee target.log
```

What I did was convert it to:

```
target:
        (try_making_target || rm -f $@) |& tee target.log
        test -e $@
```

The the piped command fails, the "fallback" (command after ||) will delete the goal file, and the final test will fail. Note that this example assumes the OS is Linux ('rm' for deletions) and that your shell supports the || operator.

This assumes that you are not interested in partial results when **try_making_target** fails. If you want to keep partial result in 'target', you can use other "marker" files to designate the success or failure of **try_making_target**. Something like this may work:

```
target:
        touch $@.succeeded                                          # Assume success
        (try_making_target || rm -f $@.succeeded) |& tee target.log # Delete to mark failure
        test -e $@.succeeded                                        # Fail if marker
        rm $@.succeeded                                             # Remove unneeded marker
```

This last code would also work for phony goals, although you really should minimize the use of these (I try only using them as mnemonics for real files, which may have longish names).